# Position required parameters at the top of help pages

Tags: discussion, status-completed, documentation

The required `id` parameter for ...a lot of API routes... is now placed at the bottom of the page.

It makes more sense to place required parameters at the top of the page with a slight separation, like an `<hr>` or an icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are now sorted by whether or not they are required (required on top) and then by name.

Comment: you are like the shoemaker's elves.